# Retrieve dynamic margin of button in PyQt 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I have a widget, usually but not always a button, which I'd like to animate the margin and width of to emulate a scroll-in effect. However, different widgets have different margins, as set in Qt Designer with CSS. I need to retrieve the margin, which the documentation says I can do via `child.contentsMargins()`. This is incorrect because:

- `widget.contentsMargins()` returns `0, 0, 0, 0`. The actual margins are `20, 20, 0, 0`.
- `widget.style().subElementRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_PushButtonFocusRect, QtWidgets.QStyleOptionButton())` returns `2, 3, -4, -6`, which doesn't seem to be related to anything anywhere.
- `widget.style().subElementRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_PushButtonFocusRect, QtWidgets.QStyleOptionButton(), widget)` returns `21, 21, -22, -22`, which also doesn't seem to be related to anything anywhere.

The only option I see is to parse the stylesheet and dynamically update it, once per frame, but I really don't want to go through string manipulation for every frame of the animation because dear god that's a hideous way to animate something smoothly. Is there no way to access these values built in?

Update: simple reproduction:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
QtWidgets.QApplication([])
b = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
b.setStyleSheet("margin: 15px")
b.contentsMargins().top() #is 0, should be 15
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: That should take care of it…